# How can I go to the next activity instead of previous activity after scanning QR code

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout

***Hello everyone,
Currently I am working on android project and I stuck at this step. So, please tell me How can I go to the next activity instead of previous activity after scanning QR code
scanning result should be pass to next activity textview.
Please help me out as soon as possible
Tahnk you***

// qr scanner

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class Qrscanner extends AppCompatActivity implements  ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

    ZXingScannerView scannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView) ;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Dexter.withContext(getApplicationContext())
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        scannerView.startCamera();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        Products_n_quantity.customerinfo.setText(rawResult.getText());
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Products_n_quantity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        scannerView.startCamera();
    }
}


//next activity

package com.example.android.aarmanmilk;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.common.math.Quantiles;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Products_n_quantity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner product, quantity;
    public static TextView customerinfo ;
    Button delivered;
    TextView c_name;

    ArrayList<String> product_array;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter_product;

    ArrayList<String> quantity_array_other ;
    ArrayList<String> quantity_array;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter_quantity_array_other;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_n_quantity);

        product = findViewById(R.id.productspinner);
        quantity = findViewById(R.id.quantityspinner);
        customerinfo = findViewById(R.id.customername);
        delivered = findViewById(R.id.btndeliver) ;
        c_name = findViewById(R.id.cname);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        product_array = new ArrayList<>();
        product_array.add("Milk");
        product_array.add("Yoghurt");
        product_array.add("Paneer");
        product_array.add("Shrikhand");
        product_array.add("Amrakhand");

        arrayAdapter_product = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, product_array);
        product.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_product);

        quantity_array_other = new ArrayList<>();
        quantity_array_other.add("250 mg");
        quantity_array_other.add("500 mg");
        quantity_array_other.add("750 mg");
        quantity_array_other.add("1 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("1.25 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("1.5 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("1.75 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("2 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("2.25 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("2.5 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("2.75 kg");
        quantity_array_other.add("3 kg");

        quantity_array = new ArrayList<>();
        quantity_array.add("250 ml");
        quantity_array.add("500 ml");
        quantity_array.add("750 ml");
        quantity_array.add("1 L");
        quantity_array.add("1.25 L");
        quantity_array.add("1.5 L");
        quantity_array.add("1.75 L");
        quantity_array.add("2 L");
        quantity_array.add("2.25 L");
        quantity_array.add("2.5 L");
        quantity_array.add("2.75 L");
        quantity_array.add("3 L");

        product.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    arrayAdapter_quantity_array_other = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, quantity_array);
                }

                if (position == 1|| position == 2 || position == 3 || position == 4); {
                    arrayAdapter_quantity_array_other  = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, quantity_array_other);
                }

                quantity.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_quantity_array_other);

                quantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        //String selected_product = product.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        //String selected_quantity = quantity.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you selected " +selected_product+ " "+selected_quantity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        delivered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Date dt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                String currentDate = dt.toString() ;
                String c_mobile = c_name.getText().toString();
                customerinfo.setText(c_mobile);

                //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                //String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
                //String cn = c_name.getText().toString() ;

                String selected_product = product.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String selected_quantity = quantity.getSelectedItem().toString();

                HashMap<String, Object> pq = new HashMap<>();
                pq.put("Product", selected_product);
                pq.put("Quantity", selected_quantity);

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customers").child(c_mobile).child(currentDate).updateChildren(pq).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Products_n_quantity.this, selected_product + " " + selected_quantity + " delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Products_n_quantity.this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you call onBackpressed() in handelResult

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, I want to save the scanned result in customerinfo textview and enter into that activity which has textview customerinfo. But instead of entering into that activity, the app goes directly to previous activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    Scanners.scanqr.setText(rawResult.getText());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Products_n_quantity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: this can't stop scanning

Comment: add `finish();` after `startActivity();`